# Options for logging Windows Store apps

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

So I'm creating many Windows (8) Store apps and I'm wondering what are my best choices to help my users but possible bugs (if they ever occour).

I was thinking about a log4net like solution to a rollingFile. Or maybe on the appcrashed event send a crash report to my own server.

What are my options? what's the "best" option?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the new Google Analytics service. Just add the free [Google Analytics SDK for Windows 8](http://googleanalyticssdk.codeplex.com) to your app and automatically track unhandled exceptions (or add 1 line of code to track them manually). Super easy, plus you get a ton of great analytics tracking for your app.

Comment: This SDK drags in C# Runtime into a JS app which is not recommended. Getting GA to work is really easy though, with pure JS as illustrated with this: http://pastebin.com/PjZkEuqs

Comment: Update: There's now a new version of the Google Analytics SDK for Win8 and WP (above) that includes a fully native (C++/CX) version to avoid the CLR dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have to say, the code looks rather complex. Compared to ~100 Lines of clean JS code, the C++ variant is a monster. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use log4javascript and use the RollingFileAppender from here: http://pastebin.com/MdCtjGt8 It uses the momentjs lib to calculate the file name but you can substitute this with your own calculation.